# How do I use a String Array from another Class?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do I perform the perfectShuffle operation to my "deck" array?

I do not know how to import the "deck" array into my perfectShuffle method/class (idk wtf is the difference)

This Does NOT compile because my perfectShuffle cant find ''deck''

I'm pretty sure you're gonna look at my code and be like 'wtf do u even know what you're doing?' well no I dont know what i'm doing but ive gotten super far with not knowing what im doing by creating a deck array of every card in a deck of cards.

Im struggling to find the flow from class/method/object/instance watever and how they interact.

Any help or points to resources is greatly appreciated.

```
public String[] Deck(){
    String[] deck = new String[52];

    //Populate Deck 2-10
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++){
        if (i<9){
            for (int j=2; j<=10; j++){
                deck[i]=(j+" of Clubs");
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (12<i&&i<22){
            for (int j=2; j<=10; j++){
                deck[i]=(j+" of Diamonds");
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (25<i&&i<35){
            for (int j=2; j<=10; j++){
                deck[i]=(j+" of Hearts");
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (38<i&&i<48){
            for (int j=2; j<=10; j++){
                deck[i]=(j+" of Spades");
                i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            deck[9]=("Jack of Clubs");
            deck[10]=("Queen of Clubs");
            deck[11]=("King of Clubs");
            deck[12]=("Ace of Clubs");

            deck[22]=("Jack of Diamonds");
            deck[23]=("Queen of Diamonds");
            deck[24]=("King of Diamonds");
            deck[25]=("Ace of Diamonds");

            deck[35]=("Jack of Hearts");
            deck[36]=("Queen of Hearts");
            deck[37]=("King of Hearts");
            deck[38]=("Ace of Hearts");

            deck[48]=("Jack of Spades");
            deck[49]=("Queen of Spades");
            deck[50]=("King of Spades");
            deck[51]=("Ace of Spades");
        }
    }
}
private void perfectShuffle(){
    Deck();
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++){
        deck[i]=deck[i+26];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++){
        System.out.println(deck[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perfectShuffle` does not have access to the local variables locked away inside of `Deck()`. You need to grab the value that `Deck` returns, and make good use of it:

```
private void perfectShuffle(){
    String[] myDeck = Deck();
    for (int i=0; i<27; i++){
        myDeck[i]=myDeck[i+26];
    }
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++){
        System.out.println(myDeck[i]);
    }
}
```

Likewise, you need to make `Deck()` actually return that string array, as you have declared the method to return a `String[]`:

```
public String[] Deck(){
    String[] deck = new String[52];

    //Populate Deck 2-10
    for (int i=0; i<52; i++){
        // blah blah blah
    }

    return deck;
}
```

Comment: MattBot does not recognize this "hu-man" of which you question

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, I've just been around for a while.

Comment: yeah i had to wait 8 minutes lol, ive been spamming it
i cant upvote it cuz i dont have nuff rep